# Twilio: Could not connect to Live: Signaling connection disconnected

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I use Twilio for a while, and today when I try to create a video Room,
The LED in my web cam appears then disappears and Twilio says this message:

> Could not connect to Live: **Signaling connection disconnected**

When I do *Inspect Element* in Firefox I see this:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://sdkgw.us1.twilio.com/v1/VideoEvents.

This is how I used to connect with **js**

```
var connectOptions = {
    name: room_name,
}
Twilio.Video.connect(token, connectOptions).then(roomJoined, function(error) {
    var text = ('Could not connect to Live: ' + error.message )
    ring('danger',text);
}
```

Does someone know what is wrong?

Comment: The web socket connection is used to pass signalling information between peers joining a room and is performed by the JS SDK. Did you have a stable network connection at the time? Are you able to connect now or is this a persistent issue now?

Comment: Fixed, the problem was the network connection

Answer (score 1):

According to this [bug report](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice.js/issues/31), this is possible if your token has expired. Instead of throwing a 20104, it throws  53000. Check your token. It was the same in my case.

Comment: thanks you save my day, due expired token I was facing a 53000 error in javascript voice SDK it's fixed now just because of you